# HTML form with validation

Tags: javascript, php, html, csv

I have a HTML form with validation that works well, but if I add info saving to php file, then it does not validate. It should check if the entered values are correct and if so then save the info to .csv file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Greaton</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="all" />
    <script src="validation.js"></script>  
</head>
<body>

    <form name="form" method="post" action="csv.php">
        <div class="container">
            <div  class="form">
                <center><img src="logo.jpg" alt="logo" width="200"     height="40"></center>
                </br>

                <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus dapibus enim a 
                adipiscing hendrerit. Nam vei orci vitae metus posuere rhncus sed ac augue. 
                Aenean tempus, lectus a rhoncus vulputate, nisi tellus commodo quam, sit amet 
                egestas magna elit ac mauris. Name pretium erat leo,
                id dignissim tortor tincidunt sed. Morbi id est ut tellus euismd convallis.</h1>

                <h2>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. 
                Fusce egestas egestan ante, nec lobortis elit luctus id. Ut vulputate sem sit amet ipsum pretium, 
                feugiat gravida elit blandit. Donec varius omale mi, posuere rutrum erat placerat a.</h2>

                <h2>Maecenas ullamcorper euismod justo vei dictum. <a href="">Aenean sodales fringilla</a></h2>
                </br>
                <label for="nimi">Nimi:</label>
                <input id="nimi" class="contact" name="nimi" placeholder="Nimi Nimeste"  tabindex="1" type="text" > 
                </br>

                <label for="uisik">Isikukood:</label>
                <input id="isikukood" class="contact" name="isik" placeholder="isikukood"  type="text" > <br>
                <label for="sugu"> Sugu:</label>
                <label for="mees">Mees</label>
                 <input id="mees" class="contact" type="radio" name="Sugu" value="Mees" />
                <label for="naine">Naine</label>
                <input id="naine" class="contact" type="radio" name="Sugu" value="Naine" />
                </br>

                <label for="sunniaasta"> Sünniaasta:</label>
                <input class="sunniaasta" maxlength="4" name="sunniaasta" placeholder="Sünniaasta" >
                </br>

                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                <input id="email" class="contact" ="email" placeholder="greaton@greaton.ee"  type="email"> </br>

                <label for="telefon">Telefon:</label>
                <input id="telefon" class="contact" name="telefon" placeholder="55555555"  type="text"> 
                </br>

                <label for="asukoht"> Asukoht:</label>
                <select class="select" name="asukoht">
                    <option selected>Vali asukoht</option>
                    <option>Harju Maakond</option>
                    <option >Hiiu Maakond</option>
                    <option>Ida-Viru Maakond</option>
                    <option>Jõgeva Maakond</option>
                    <option>Järva Maakond</option>
                </select>
                </br>

                <label for="lisainfo">Lisainfo:</label>
                <div  class="text">

                    <textarea name="lisainfo" rows="8" class="contact" input id="lisainfo" cols="74"></textarea>
                    </br>

                    <input id="tingimused" class="contact" type="checkbox" name="tingimused" required="" type="text">Nõustun reeglite ja tingimustega <br>

                    <input id="uudiskiri" class="contact" type="checkbox" name="uudiskiri" type="text">
                    Soovin tellida uudiskirja<br>
                    <br>

                    <input class="buttom" name="submit" id="submit" tabindex="5" value="Esitan Avalduse" type="submit">

                </div>
           </form> 
        </div>      
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

You see below all my validation functions:

```
function formValidation() {

    var uname = document.registration.nimi;
    var uadd = document.registration.isikukood;
    var asukoht = document.registration.asukoht;
    var telefon = document.registration.telefon;
    var uemail = document.registration.email;
    var umsex = document.registration.msex;
    var ufsex = document.registration.fsex; 

    {
    if(allLetter(uname)) {

        if(alphanumeric(uadd)) { 
            var telefon = document.registration.telefon;
            var uemail = document.registration.email;
            var umsex = document.registration.msex;
            var ufsex = document.registration.fsex; 
        {

        if(allLetter(uname)) {
            if(alphanumeric(uadd)) { 
                if(koht(asukoht)) {
                    if(allnumeric(telefon)) {
                        if(ValidateEmail(uemail)) {
                            if(validsex(umsex,ufsex)) {
                            }
                        } 
                    }
                } 
            }
        }

    }
}

return false;

function allLetter(uname) { 
    var letters = /^[A-Za-z0-9- ]/;
    if(uname.value.match(letters)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        alert('nimi on vale');
        uname.focus();
        return false;
    }
}

function alphanumeric(uadd) { 
    var letters = /^[0-9]{11}$/;
    if(uadd.value.match(letters)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        alert('vale isikukood');
        uadd.focus();
         return false;
    }
}

function koht(asukoht) {
    if(asukoht.value == "Default") {
        alert('Palu vali midagi listist');
        asukoht.focus();
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

function allnumeric(telefon) { 
    var numbers = /^[0-9]+$/;
    if(telefon.value.match(numbers)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        alert('Telefoninumbris tohivad olla ainult numbrid');
        telefon.focus();
        return false;
    }
}

function ValidateEmail(uemail) {
    var mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
    if(uemail.value.match(mailformat)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        alert("Vale email");
        uemail.focus();
        return false;
    }
} 

function validsex(umsex,ufsex) {
    x=0;

    if(umsex.checked) {
        x++;
    } 
    if(ufsex.checked) {
        x++; 
    }
    if(x==0) {
        alert('Select Male/Female');
        umsex.focus();
        return false;
    } else {
        alert('Form Succesfully Submitted');
        window.location.reload()
        return true;
    }
}
```

And the file csv.php which interact with the form value

```
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) { 
        $name = $_POST["nimi"]; 
        $isik = $_POST["isik"]; 
        $sunniaasta = $_POST["sunniaasta"]; 
        $sugu = $_POST["sugu"]; 
        $email = $_POST["email"]; 
        $telefon = $_POST["telefon"]; 
        $asukoht = $_POST["asukoht"]; 
        $lisainfo = $_POST["lisainfo"]; 

        $cvsData ='"Nimi","Isikukood","sunniaasta","sugu","email","telefon","asukoht","lisainfo"'.PHP_EOL; 
        $cvsData .= "\"$name\",\"$isik\",\"$sunniaasta\",\"$sugu\",\"$email\",\"$telefon\",\"$asukoht\",\"$lisainfo\"".PHP_EOL; 
        $fp = fopen("test.csv", "a"); 

        if($fp) { 
            fwrite($fp,$cvsData); // Write information to the file 
            fclose($fp); // Close the file 
        } 
    } 
?>
```

Thank you for your attention !

Comment: show us your validation code, are you preventing the default events by `return false;`?

Comment: function allLetter(uname)
{ 
var letters = /^[A-Za-z0-9- ]/;
if(uname.value.match(letters))
{
return true;
}
else
{
alert('nimi on vale');
uname.focus();
return false;
}
}

Comment: Please update your question, don't try to write code in comments.

Comment: where are you executing it?

Comment: What do you mean by _if I add info saving to php file_?

Comment: Please post the complete code that you are working..

Comment: the csv.php puts the info i entered and saves it to csv file

Comment: where is your call to the javascript function, do you even use something like `onsubmit = ...`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem:**

Its only happens because when you call the php with your action property its directly pass the value without calling your JavaScript function.

**Solution:**

Remove the action tag and method tag from your html form and append an ajax with your ValidateEmail function to pass the data to your csv.php file.

**Example:**

```
     function ValidateEmail(uemail)

            {
                 //change the last else part to this:
                  else
                   {
                     msg=callPHP();
                     if(msg=="true")
                        alert('Form Succesfully Submitted');
                     else
                         alert('fail Submitted');
                     window.location.reload()
                     return true;
                    }
              }
          function callPHP(){
                     //change the else part  use ajax to call the php here.


                   var uname = document.registration.nimi;
                   var uadd = document.registration.isikukood;
                   var asukoht = document.registration.asukoht;
                   var telefon = document.registration.telefon;
                   var uemail = document.registration.email;
                   var umsex = document.registration.msex;
                   var ufsex = document.registration.fsex; 

                           $.ajax({
                               type:'POST',
                               url: "csv.php",
                               data: {uname:uname.value,uadd:uadd.value,asukoht:asukoht.value,...,...//like this pass the data to the php},
                               dataType:'JSON'
                               success:function(json)
                                       {
                                          //enter your result here.....
                                           return json[0].response;
                                       }

                             }
```

**PHP**

```
      <?php 

                 $name       = $_POST["nimi"]; 
                 $isik       = $_POST["isik"];                      
                 $sugu       = $_POST["sugu"]; 
                 $email      = $_POST["email"]; 
                 $telefon    = $_POST["telefon"]; 
                 $asukoht    = $_POST["asukoht"]; 
                 $lisainfo   = $_POST["lisainfo"]; 
                 $sunniaasta = $_POST["sunniaasta"]; 

                 $cvsData = '"Nimi","Isikukood","sunniaasta","sugu","email","telefon","asukoht","lisainfo"'.PHP_EOL;   
                 $cvsData .= "\"$name\",\"$isik\",\"$sunniaasta\",\"$sugu\",\"$email\",\"$telefon\",\"$asukoht\",\"$lisainfo\"".PHP_EOL; 
                 $fp = fopen("test.csv", "a"); 

                if($fp) 
                    { 
                        fwrite($fp,$cvsData); // Write information to the file 
                        fclose($fp); // Close the file 

                        $data[]=array('respons'=> 'true');
                    } 


                      json_encode($data);


        ?>
```

hope it will work...